# How to profile sqlite query execution against the query plan?

Tags: performance, sqlite

I'm familliar with the EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN commands. However, these only show how the query *will* be executed. I would like to be able to compare the query plan with data from the actual execution. In particular, I'd like to see the number of rows accessed and returned from every step of the query plan as well as the wall/cpu time each step took.

Comment: I have removed the <sql> tag since this is a very sqlite specific question.

Answer (score 0):

There is [sqlite3_stmt_scanstatus_v2](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt_scanstatus.html), which is available in the SQLite CLI with the `.scanstats` command, but the compile time option `SQLITE_ENABLE_STMT_SCANSTATUS` is required for this to work and that is not a default option. If your version of the library is compiled with that option set, you can additionally use [sqlite3_trace_v2](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/trace_v2.html) to automatically gather the statistics after a statement has finished executing.